# Deployment alchemy websocket server c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket

I have problem with how deploy [alchemy web socket server](http://alchemywebsockets.net/) ..
Server is C# console application, and It has install exe file either.

On their sites wrote, that :
*"You can run Alchemy Websockets as a console application, Windows service, Linux daemon under Mono, or any configuration that works best for you."*

How to deploy ?

I have asp.NET MVC apliaction with uses this server to chat, but I have no Idea How to deploy my site with separate project (server as a console app) to hosting provider.

Thank you vary much for help !